# Evaluating a function using all possible row pairs

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas in Python 3, I have created a dataframe. Multiple measurements were taken under 4 different sets of conditions (L1, L2, L3, L4) and each row is a specific measurement containing distribution parameters for pixel brightness in a photograph before and after an event. Here is an example I invented for our discussion:

```
Data = {'Picture_Type' : ['L1','L1','L1','L2','L2','L2','L3','L3','L3',
                          'L4','L4','L4'],
        'Before Mean' : [9,10,11,14,16,18,26,29,32,37,40,43],
        'Before StdDev' : [1,1.1,1.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,2.1,2.3,2.5,1.5,1.6,1.7],
        'After Mean' : [6,7,8,11,12,13,19,21,23,27,30,33],
        'After StdDev' : [0.7,0.8,0.9,1.3,1.5,1.7,2.5,2.7,2.9,1.5,1.6,1.7]}
df = DataFrame(Data)
print(df)

   Picture_Type  Before Mean  Before StdDev  After Mean  After StdDev
0            L1            9            1.0           6           0.7
1            L1           10            1.1           7           0.8
2            L1           11            1.2           8           0.9
3            L2           14            0.7          11           1.3
4            L2           16            0.8          12           1.5
5            L2           18            0.9          13           1.7
6            L3           26            2.1          19           2.5
7            L3           29            2.3          21           2.7
8            L3           32            2.5          23           2.9
9            L4           37            1.5          27           1.5
10           L4           40            1.6          30           1.6
11           L4           43            1.7          33           1.7
```

I need to evaluate a function that requires input from all possible row pairings and I would like to aggregate those calculations by 'Picture_Type' so that I end up with a grid like this:

```
     L1    L2    L3    L4
L1    *     *     *     *
L2    *     *     *     *   
L3    *     *     *     *  
L4    *     *     *     *
```

where * would be the aggregated result for the row/column combination in which it appears.

I am computing the KL-divergence of a Gaussian Mixture Model. For each pair of rows, I compute a mixture of "before" distributions and a mixture of "after" distributions, then compute the divergence between the two mixtures. Each row pair provides the 8 parameters I need to perform the calculation and I aggregate each category with an arithmetic average. Thus in this example, I would perform 144 distinct calculations (as there are 12x12 row pairings) and sort them into 16 categories (L1&L1, L1&L2, L1&L3, L1&L4, L2&L1, …) and each category would be an average of the 9 measurement pairs in each category.

I have already figured out the code for my calculations, but I just can't see how to step through all the combinations and organize the results. I thought about computing the required value for each row pair and binning them according to the 'Picture_Type' pairing, but I can't see how to pull that off.

I have been looking around for other code examples and I have found bits and pieces that might be useful, but I cannot see how to pull it together. I am new to all this and am learning on the fly at work, but if anyone can point me in the proper direction I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you explain more or output sample for the L2*L1 result ? I dont really understand what is should do. (waht are your 16 cat and 9 mesurement ?.) thank you

Comment: How to aggregate the for measurements?  Sum, Mean, Max, Min?

Comment: What would the actual values in the grid be for this example?

Comment: I am computing the KL-divergence of a Gaussian Mixture Model. For each pair of rows, I compute a before mixture and an after mixture, then compute the divergence between the two mixtures. Each row pair provides the 8 parameters I need to perform the calculation and I aggregate each category with an arithmetic average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have maybe a partial answer for you, but since I'm not clear on your functions, I'll leave that part to you.

First step is to get a list of all the possible pair combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations as cb
pairs = list(cb(range(11), 2))
print(pairs)

[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (8, 9), (8, 10), (9, 10)]
```

If you are looking for all possible combinations in either direction use itertools.product

If you insert one of these pairs into df.loc you get:

```
df.loc[(0,1),:]
```

giving...

```
 Picture_Type  Before Mean  Before StdDev  After Mean  After StdDev
0           L1            9            1.0           6           0.7
1           L1           10            1.1           7           0.8
```

Then iterate through these pairs to create all combinations of rows, at which point you can apply your functions and recreate a new dataframe.

```
for n in range(len(pairs)):
    print('\npair...', pairs[n])
    df_pair = df.loc[pairs[n],:]
    s1 = df_pair.iloc[0]
    s2 = df_pair.iloc[1]

    print("Series 1\n", s1)
    print("Series 2\n", s2)



pair... (0, 1)
Series 1
 Picture_Type      L1
Before Mean        9
Before StdDev      1
After Mean         6
After StdDev     0.7
Name: 0, dtype: object
Series 2
 Picture_Type      L1
Before Mean       10
Before StdDev    1.1
After Mean         7
After StdDev     0.8
Name: 1, dtype: object

pair... (0, 2)
Series 1
 Picture_Type      L1
Before Mean        9
Before StdDev      1
After Mean         6
After StdDev     0.7
Name: 0, dtype: object
Series 2
 Picture_Type      L1
Before Mean       11
Before StdDev    1.2
After Mean         8
After StdDev     0.9
Name: 2, dtype: object

...etc...
```

**EDIT

I will try to add the rest of what you might be looking for but I'm not  sure about the equations, so I will use a simple substitute equation.

OK Lets say for simplicity sake your are adding Before Mean to Before StdDev and After Mean to After StdDev, and for both rows, than subtracting them from each other.

If you enter each pair into a df.loc you get the following:

```
result_dict = {}
for n in range(len(pairs)):
    df_pair = df.loc[pairs[n],:]
    s1 = df_pair.iloc[0]
    s2 = df_pair.iloc[1]

    s1_b = s1['Before Mean'] + s1['Before StdDev']
    s1_a = s1['After Mean'] + s1['After StdDev']
    s2_b = s2['Before Mean'] + s2['Before StdDev']
    s2_a = s2['After Mean'] + s2['After StdDev']

    result = (s1_a - s1_b) - (s2_a - s2_b)

    result_dict[pairs[n]] = s1['Picture_Type'], s2['Picture_Type'], result

df_result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict).T

df_result.columns = ['PT1', 'PT2','result']   
df_result.groupby(["PT1", "PT2"]).sum().unstack(1)


   result                  
PT2     L1    L2    L3    L4
PT1                         
L1     0.0   0.0  38.7  40.2
L2     0.0   0.0  38.7  40.2
L3   -38.7 -38.7   0.0  14.4
L4   -40.2 -40.2 -14.4   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! I see how to make this work for my problem. The function is a Simpson Rule approximation for an improper integral. The integrable function consists of two Gaussian Mixture model distributions, p and q, that are combined as p*log(p/q). So its a bit involved and completely tangental to this, so I omitted it.